# sql single big view vs. union of views

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a root table, let's call it **Study**, and several child tables. The **Study** table has a unique ID and one other field relevant to this question: **Study type** - this is an enumeration field, there are currently 8 possible study types. Each row is one and only one study type.
I also have 8 views, one for each Study type. Each view has logic to compute a new field called **Study name** - the logic to compute this field is different for each study type, using different fields from child tables, different lookup tables, etc. This is why the 8 separate views were created.
I now need to create a *combined* view that has all the rows from the Study table AND for each row also includes the **Study name** field, which is currently computed in the 8 views depending on study type.

So my question is: what's the best way to do this? Assume I have control over the DB structure, I can create what I need including indexes. The options that come to mind are:

1. UNION ALL across the 8 views. My worry here is performance, as I will then need to use the combined view to run several reports with their own filters, I'm not sure if indexes from the source tables would be preserved after the union.
2. Write a single view that combines the logic from the current 8 views into one big view, using CASE statements to execute the correct Study name logic on a row-by-row basis depending on study type.
3. Something else I haven't thought of? Maybe 8 stored procedures that just compute the 8 different study types, and a single view that calls them?

Thanks -

Comment: 1 way that generally has better performance than a view could be Table Valued Function with Case statements to replace all 8 views and the 1 all encompassing of everything you want.  Without know or having an idea of the logic differences for study name it is pretty much impossible for people to answer this because it is very broad and opinion based

Comment: You can [**create Index view**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.105).aspx) for each small view. But you are right after the union that view wont have any index. I probably go with the big View and create one index for it.

Comment: @Matt what additional information would be useful? In terms of logic for the views, all 8 have a long CASE statement that uses 1 to 4 fields in a couple of child tables, to determine the study name for that row. I can provide a small code snippet if it would be useful.

Comment: You to understand the problem and the solutions so I assume you're looking for opinions on the better solution.  Performance aside, I prefer the union all option because you're only storing your business logic in the original view and not in multiple views. Encapsulating your rules like that will make your solution more transparent, maintainable and ultimately more robust.  So I'd first test performance on the "union all" solution.  Look at the query plan - you may find that your optimizer fixes any bottlenecks.

Comment: @Bob doesn't UNION ALL have the opposite effect? It would mean that I continue to have the Study name logic spread over 8 views, and do a UNION ALL to put them back together. I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @CPCode 1-4 columns and child tables help but the curiousity for performance etc will it be the same child tables or will you end up with way more joins in a combined view etc.  I agree to your response to Bob I would think you want your logic consolidated for business purposes.  So I if all same child tables (or near same) I would suggest either 1 big view that everything is in and when you call it you always use a where type = or a table valued function [TVF]

Comment: TVF is great because you can limit the result set prior to looking at everything that would be in the big view so more effectively filter.  And sql can cache execution plans which can help performance (maybe). But if your child tables are different then maintaining separate views for everything could be better.

Comment: I think I worded that oddly.  The logic would be encapsulated in a single view for each of the 8 Study types.  Then the union all is just a very simple select from each view.  That just feels more clean and modular to me.

If you're able, you may find that you can push the more complex business logic into a function (Scalar or, as Matt suggested, Table Valued)

I've come to value readability and maintenance over performance as long as performance meets a certain reasonable threshold.